# A Paper Record is What I Hamper

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I can be used to mark your place,
>   When, with less than ten, you will face,
>   I can be found at your feet,
>   There is a flat surface at my peak,    
>   I come in once the votes are cast,
>   With me you can try to visit the past,
>   I'll demonstrate for you a melody.
>   An equivalent is a piece of me.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line and the title in your answer.**

**Hint**

> My glass can be found on the bed.

Comment: could the hint have anything to do with n obql bs jngre

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These clues seem to add up to give a

> counter.

I can be used to mark your place,

> A token used as a place marker in board games.

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> Prefixing (t)en, gives encounter, which is to meet or face.

I can be found at your feet,

> A stiff piece of material at the back part of a shoe, enclosing the heel.

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> Adding top for peak gives countertop, which is a flat surface.

I come in once the votes are cast,

> The election vote counters.

With me you can try to visit the past,

> Counterclockwise, which may also mean the hands of a clock going back in time.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> To point is to demonstrate, and a counterpoint is a melody.

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> A part is a piece, and a counterpart is an equal.

Title: A Paper Record is What I Hamper

> A counterfoil is a paper record kept by the person issuing it, with foil meaning to hamper. Thanks to hexomino for the extra help!

Hint:

> A glass (pane) that is found on the bed is a counterpane, which is a bedspread.

Comment: Great +1! You are mostly spot on here, there are three clues which are not quite right. (i) "flat surface" - needs a little wordplay, (ii) "visit the past" - how do you measure time, (iii) "paper record" - wordplay again, what is another word for hamper?

Comment: @hexomino - I'm unsure: (i) rot13(pbhagregbc) (ii) rot13(pbhagrepybpxjvfr) (iii) rot13(pbhagrepurpx?)

Comment: (i) yes, (ii) yes, (iii) no, think of what a paper record might be.

Comment: @hexomino - I need more help! The paper record could be a note, so perhaps rot13(pbhagresrvg?)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps it's an unfamiliar word. Okay, one more hint: Instead of "hamper", I could have use "thwart" or "obstruct" but this word could also be described as a  "sword" or perhaps a "sheet of metal".

Comment: Aha, thank you! I've added an explanation for the title now.

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer, but enough of these are spot on that I feel like I gotta be close:

> Note

I can be used to mark your place,

> You can mark your place with a note

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> I'm fairly certain this refers to the spaces on a musical staff which represent the notes F, A, C, E, but this only works on the treble clef, which is why I'm confused by "less than ten", which I read as "below tenor", but the only common clef below tenor would be the bass clef, where the spaces read A, C, E, G, unless you mean the spaces below the lines, in which case you've got F, A, C, E, and um, G, but maybe we ignore that?

I can be found at your feet,

> Footnotes

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> Barred notes like ♫ often have a flat surface on top.

I come in once the votes are cast,

> This one I'm not sure about.  Maybe notes from news pundits reporting on elections or something?

With me you can try to visit the past,

> You can take notes to try and remember stuff later.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Musical notes, clearly, as discussed above.

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> Another word for note is "memo", and a piece of "memo" is "me", though that's kind of in reverse, but wordplay is like that sometimes...

A Paper Record is What I Hamper

> Notes are of course, paper records.  Possible dig at a certain head of state recently complaining about lawyers taking notes hampering his ability to lie about stuff later?  Trying to keep the politics out of the puzzling...

Comment: Maybe rot13(geroyr pyrs unf r S t N o P q R s : n gbgny bs 9 abgrf)?

Comment: I think rot13(cvrprf bs cncref pbhyq or pbafvqrerq abgrf). In that case "I come in once the votes are cast" is self-explanatory, and "An equivalent is a piece of me" could also refer to rot13(grne n cvrpr bhg bs n cvrpr bs cncre, vg orpbzrf n arj cvrpr bs cncre)

Comment: This is a very nice answer and fits several of the clues very well. You are getting into the wordplay like I hoped. It's not right, the actual answer fits better but +1 for the effort. I will probably add a hint in a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative answer:

> Penny

I can be used to mark your place,

> Coins are often used as golf markers

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> You will have to use pennies in some denomination if you have less than 10 cents

I can be found at your feet,

> Find a penny, pick it up. You know the saying.

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> Either a reference to the bank on the coin (the top of the bank is flat) or the edge of a coin which is flat.

I come in once the votes are cast,

> Money is donated during elections, or perhaps something to do with a count?

With me you can try to visit the past,

> Coins have various prints throughout the years. You could also used money to travel.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Pink Floyd's "Money" has the sound of coins clinking/a cash register/the cha-ching sound of money, or perhaps a reference to when a coin spins around and around before it falls>?

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> There are different denominations of coins.

TITLE:

> Coins prevent physical money from being entirely note-based.

Comment: This is actually a little bit closer than your first answer (I would say the closest answer so far) but still not there as you can probably tell. There is more wordplay involved with the correct answer and it will fit a lot better to the clues.

Comment: What about nickles?

Answer (score 5):

Never tried this so hope I'm doing it right.

> The letter I

I can be used to mark your place

> Using "Aye" to confirm your presence

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> The roman numeral for 9 (one less than 10) is IX, facing an "I" with less than 10

I can be found at your feet,

> Still trying to figure this out

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> The letter I has a flat top (at least in most fonts)

I come in once the votes are cast,

> The "ayes" have it

With me you can try to visit the past,

> We use our "Eyes" constantly to view old photos, videos, read, etc.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Reference to the "Eye" of the tiger?

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> An "I" is just a line, so pieces of it are still "I"s

In reference to the hint

> "Eye"glasses are commonly kept on the nightstand near the bed

---

Forgot the title:

> Reference to eye-witness accounts being less reliable than written word over time?

Comment: This is a very creative answer and you're able to fit several of the clues quite well (so +1 at least) but it's not the right answer I'm afraid. In the hint, I do mean "on the bed". Also, in the first line it's mark your "place", not "attendance". Feel free to keep trying though.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's...

> a ruler

I can be used to mark your place,
When, with less than ten, you will face,

> You can mark you place with a ruler, some tape measures have a max of 10'.

I can be found at your feet,

> Rulers measure in feet.

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> The top of a ruler is flat.

I come in once the votes are cast,

> A ruler ascends to power once voted in.

With me you can try to visit the past,

> You can visit the past reading history based on the rulers of those times

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> There's a band named Melody Ruler... or... melodies or songs are written in measures.

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> A broken ruler is still capable of measuring lengths.

Title:

> A ruler can be set on a piece of paper to hamper it when drawing lines so that it doesn't move, or simply as a paperweight.

Comment: This is a good attempt but you can see there are a few lines which don't quite fit (especially the 2nd and 4th and the title) - also I don't think there is a band with this name but there is a song. There is a bit more wordplay involved in the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Digit?

I can be used to mark your place,

> Like a queue ?

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> Digits are numbers 0-9, so not over 10, that uses multiple digits

I can be found at your feet,

> Toes can sometimes be called digits

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> Toes have toenails, which are flat

I come in once the votes are cast,

> Votes have numbers, aka digits.

With me you can try to visit the past,
I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Not really sure about these ones..

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> Basic math?

Comment: This is not the answer I'm afraid. It fits really well with the first half, which I like, but not the second half or the title.

Answer (score 3):

Wildly different direction, long shot. Trying to focus on wordplay more.

> A cross?

I can be used to mark your place,

> Crosses are often used in graves in place of headstones

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> '<'X makes a rather funny emoji/face (sorry, don't know how to escape it properly)

I can be found at your feet,

> X marks the spot!

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> The top of a cross is flat!

I come in once the votes are cast,

> Ballots are typically marked with an x

With me you can try to visit the past,

> Worldplay on "ex" - ex-girlfriend or boyfriend?

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Ex. is often short for example; short features on songs are often denoted with "Artist x Artist"

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> Could this be a reference to mathematics, eg. 'x' is an unknown quantity and as such parts of x are still denoted as number*x?

TITLE:

> This might be a reference to the 'x' on a contract/formal document, usually denoting a necessary signature to complete/officiate the document.

Comment: Although I can see your thinking with some of the lines, this isn't correct. There is a lot more wordplay involved and the wording I've chosen is pretty specific in most of the poem.

Comment: @hexomino tried a completely different direction?

Comment: The use of wordplay is certainly better this time and more along the lines of how to approach the riddle, I especially like the explanation to the "visit the past" line. You can probably feel the fact that some of the lines still don't fit. The right answer should fit better.

Answer (score 2):

My improved and new answer is:

> "Pee"?

I can be used to mark your place,

> I pee to mark my territory

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> my range is less then ten feet

I can be found at your feet,

> again I peed on the ground to make my territory

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> the liquid always tries to be straight at the surface level

I come in once the votes are cast,

> This ones a bit more complicated: people need to wait in line for a long time, so once every one is done vote everyone mostly goes pee

With me you can try to visit the past,

> archaeologist/vets/scientist use urine samples to determine information about the animal's past health and their past environment

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> peeing makes a distinct tinkle sound and a rhythm can be heard (different 
>  grounds/toilets produce different melodies)

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> if you cut pee in half you still have the same pee

Title: A Paper Record is What I Hamper

> if you have a paper record of your pee, you probably have some disease or 
>  health problems. So i would want to hamper a paper record of my pee(stay 
>  healthy).

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! I've hidden your answer behind a spoiler, please make sure to explain your reasoning as the OP suggested!

Comment: Hi @personpersonson, welcome to Puzzling SE! Your answer is lacking an explanation for why you think it is correct. [Answers without explanation are generally deleted](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1493/should-we-delete-answers-that-contain-no-explanation), so please add one as soon as you can. Thanks!

Comment: This is not the answer. In any answer you give, please explain how it fits with each line of the riddle and the title.

Comment: okay ill try to think of another one

Comment: An amusing answer certainly, but not right I'm afraid. There is more wordplay involved.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer. I think that it fits quite well with the first part and almost the second one as well.

> Score

I can be used to mark your place,

> Your score determines your place/position, as in baseball.

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> 9 (less than 10) players in a baseball team.

I can be found at your feet,

> Touching the base with your feet to secure a score.

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> A maximum of 4 sores at one hit.

I come in once the votes are cast,

> The score after counting the votes.

With me you can try to visit the past,

> A score can be an account of an event.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Score of a musical composition.

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> Not sure about it. May be 'core', as in essence, as an equivalent of score, or a partial musical composition record is still a score.

Comment: Another nice answer but not correct I'm afraid. The "flat surface"  and "feet" lines don't quite work and I don't know how the title would fit. Good attempt though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Stamp?

I can be used to mark your place,

> As in place stamps to imprint your address?

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> The receiver will have to bear the charges of the received letter if the postage stamp value is less than 10 cents (very cheap by the way)?

I can be found at your feet,

> Foot prints?

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> The stamp's peak/bottom surface is almost flat, execpt the engraved/embossed bits.

I come in once the votes are cast,

> A stamp seal to seal off the envelop.

With me you can try to visit the past,

> Postage stamps may reveal some history. Also, the time-stamps for digital content.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Tap dancing. The music produced by stamping the feet.

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> The imprint of a stamp represents the stamp's text/content.

Comment: Another good attempt and I can see where the inspiration comes from but there is more wordplay involved than this. My wording in some of the lines is very intentional.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have a stab at a partial answer. It's

> Tab

I can be used to mark your place,

> A tab in a book

When, with less than ten, you will face - can't figure out this one.

I can be found at your feet

> Shoes sometimes have velcro tabs

There is a flat surface at my peak - not sure... maybe

> When written properly capitalized as "Tab" then the highest point in the word is the letter "T" which has a flat top. Alternatively this could refer to the "Tab" key on a keyboard, which has a flat top.

I come in once the votes are cast,

> A tab, as in a tally

With me you can try to visit the past,

> Keeping tabs on someone

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Apparently a "tab" is "A form of musical notation indicating fingering rather than the pitch of notes, commonly used for stringed instruments." From Wordnik which took it from Wikitionary.

An equivalent is a piece of me - Don't know.

Paper Record is What I Hamper

> A "tab" as in a "bar tab" means a record of debt. This hampers actually paying with (paper) money, receiving a (paper) check and having it recorded.

Hint - don't know.

Comment: Quite a creative answer but this is not it. As you can see, there are several lines which don't quite fit although you are thinking along the right lines in some of them.

Comment: @hexomino - Yesss! :) I kinda feel where this is going, but no words come to mind that would fit them all. Unless this involves more languages than just English, in which case I'm probably out of luck. :P

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is

> Pole

I can be used to mark your place

> You can place a flag pole to mark your place.

When, with less than ten, you will face

> Could this be a reference to "Wouldn't touch you with a ten foot barge pole"?

I can be found at your feet

> Is this to do with "Walking poles" used to help in fell walking?

There is a flat surface at my peak

> Poles generally aren't pointed on top

I come in once the votes are cast

> I think this is a reference to "The polls are in"

With me you can try to visit the past

> I am still trying to figure this one out.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody

> You can play a song on a flute which is usually pole shaped.

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> Still no idea on this one.

Comment: Interesting answer, but not what I'm looking for. There is a lot more wordplay involved.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the hint, the answer might be

> Water

I can be used to mark your place,

> Watermark or a body of water associated with a location.

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> Pure water has a pH of 7.

I can be found at your feet,

> At the end of a waterslide.

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> The water levels its surface (as also pointed out in Person Personson's answer).

I come in once the votes are cast,

> Watershed, a critical point.

With me you can try to visit the past,

> The battle of Waterloo.

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> A waterfall. Creates a melody (perhaps not different from what Personson suggested) along with a visual effect.

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> A piece of water is still water.

The hint:

> Waterglass, a silicate used in textiles.

The title:

> Not easy to take notes on a wet paper.

Comment: Another creative answer and you're getting into the wordplay idea but some of these are a stretch. My wording in the puzzle is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Random try

> Language

I can be used to mark your place,

> Words could leave marks in peoples memory?

When, with less than ten, you will face,

> You learn how to talk before 10

I can be found at your feet,

> This I can't think of

There is a flat surface at my peak,

> Words of paper are flat

I come in once the votes are cast,

> Votes cause discussions and talkings

With me you can try to visit the past,

> History mostly are written in words

I'll demonstrate for you a melody.

> Music is a universal language

An equivalent is a piece of me.

> Other languages compared to other languages

Comment: Nice try, but there is a lot more wordplay involved in the answer. Also, the title and hint would be tricky to fit into here.